# how to pass the data in the post so that we can call the id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to pass the data in the post so that we can call the id ?

because we are trying to get the "qtopic_id" of the question but its not working and it keeps on giving me a null value.

I have tried declaring qtopic_id= 19 to see if its saving in the qtopic_id column. 
I don't have to put a specific id value to save on the following column so that it wont save on that specific id only but instead it will save on its corresponding qtopic_id.

**controller**

```
public function addChoices(){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ques','Question','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ch_des1','Choices','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ch_des2','Choices','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ch_des3','Choices','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ch_des4','Choices','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ans','Answer','required');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">','</div>');




if($this->form_validation->run() ){
echo $qtopic_id ;
$data['ques']    = ($this->input->post('ques'));
$data['ch_des1'] = ($this->input->post('ch_des1'));
$data['ch_des2'] = ($this->input->post('ch_des2'));
$data['ch_des3'] = ($this->input->post('ch_des3'));
$data['ch_des4'] = ($this->input->post('ch_des4'));
$data['ans']     = ($this->input->post('ans'));

if($id=$this->queries->registerChoices($data) )
{

$this->session->set_flashdata('message','Test Added Succesfully');
return redirect('admin/testtwo');
}
else {
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','Failed to Add Test');  
}
return redirect('admin/testtwo');
}   

else {
$this->addQuestion();
}   

}


}
```

**model:**

----updated---

```
  public function registerChoices($data) {
              echo $this->input->post('qtopic_id');


            $question_arr = [
                'ques' => $data['ques'],
                'qtopic_id' => 19


            ];

            $choices_arr = [
                'ques'    => $data['ques'],
                'ch_des1' => $data['ch_des1'],
                'ch_des2' => $data['ch_des2'],
                'ch_des3' => $data['ch_des3'],
                'ch_des4' => $data['ch_des4'],
                'ans'     => $data['ans']

            ];

   //          echo "<pre>";
            // var_dump($question_arr);
            // var_dump($choices_arr);
            // exit;

            $this->db->insert('tbl_choices',$choices_arr);
            $this->db->insert('tbl_question',$question_arr);
                    return $this->db->insert_id();


        }
```

[error messages that i encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqaal.png)

Comment: where is null error showing in model ?or in addchoices , from where are you trying to post qtopic_id  . In model u registerchoices u have tried to print qtopic_id but u have not  sent paramters qtopic_id from controller , and again you are trying to set qtopic_id  value in models , its abit confusing what do you want

Comment: your question is not clear yet, Please add more code and more clarification here

Comment: i have included the errors and add some additional codes..thank youu!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code for register choices is a bit unclear. `insert_id` isn't a function that accepts data nor does it do inserting, it simply returns the last inserted id after you perform an insert query. I think what you want is something like:

```
function registerChoices($data) {

    if ($this->db->insert('tablename', $data)) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    return false;

}
```

Usage:

```
$last_insert_id = $this->somemodel->registerChoices($data);

if ($last_insert_id) {
    echo "item with id $last_insert_id was created!";
} else {
    show_error('Query failed!');
}
```